# how to split base64 text into base64 strings c#

Tags: c#, regex, base64

I have a base64 text example:

```
UAAAAAAAAAA=AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=KAAAAAAAAAA=AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAhAAAAAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

I need to split it into sides like this:

```
UAAAAAAAAAA=

AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

KAAAAAAAAAA=

AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAhAAAAAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

I tried:

```
string base64Text = "UAAAAAAAAAA=AA....."
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9+/]*={0,2}$");
string[] base64Strings = regex.Split(base64Text);
```

Comment: You mention that you tried this code, but what was the result? And what is the question now?

Comment: With [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split), the regular expression determines **the delimiter only**, so maybe just "=+" in your case.

Comment: The original text example is also invalid, a Base64 string can't contain padding characters ("=") within the string. And if several strings are just concatenated to one, you should also be aware that not every Base64 string ends with "=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on a position where there is a char A-Z or 0-9 to the left and not a `=` char or the end of the string to the right:

```
(?<=[A-Z0-9]=)(?!=|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJbeEq/1)

```
string base64Text = @"UAAAAAAAAAA=AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=KAAAAAAAAAA=AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAhAAAAAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAAAA==";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[A-Z\d]=)(?!=|$)");
string[] base64Strings = regex.Split(base64Text);
foreach (string s in base64Strings)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output

```
UAAAAAAAAAA=
AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
KAAAAAAAAAA=
AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAhAAAAAAAAAEEAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```